# AWS IOT MQTT: Getting error ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY in chrome

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using AWS IOT MQTT protocol for realtime update on my web app, I'm getting this certificate error `net::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY` on Chrome, it's only working on localhost.

Comment: [Symantec certificates won't work from Chrome 70](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html). Most AWS services have migrated but I don't know about IoT, [I've asked in the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=287062&tstart=25) but I received no answer.

Answer (score 12):

[Symantec certificates won't work from Chrome 70](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html)

AWS just posted a solution:

- IoT endpoints can't be changed automatically like other AWS services  because IoT devices need to be updated too.
- IoT now provides a new endpoint to Amazon Trust Services (ATS), which uses a trusted certificate. They have *-ats* at the end, i.e. `example-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`. Both new and old endpoints are interoperable (the only difference is the certificate).
- New regions launched after May, 2018 serve Amazon Trust Services signed certificates only.

How to update:

- Run `aws iot describe-endpoint --endpoint-type iot:Data-ATS`
- Update the endpoint on your web app with that new URL.

More info at: [How AWS IoT Core is Helping Customers Navigate the Upcoming Distrust of Symantec Certificate Authorities](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/aws-iot-core-ats-endpoints/)

Comment: This is basically a link only answer that will become useless once the links break. Please update the answer to include the significant information here.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get your new endpoint if you're worried about adding `-ats` to wrong place in url:

1. Login to AWS account
2. Go to IoT service page
3. Select Settings from sidebar
4. Copy-paste new endpoint

It only displays updated AST endpoint, so there's no way for you to copy wrong link.